# How to re-enable the popup when device is plugin in Windows 10 through Windows Registry

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

When plugin the headphone and I selected "Mic-In" instead of "Headphone" then checked for not display that dialogue next time, so now my headphone is no sound and I'm stuck, suppose the Realtek HD Audio manager have an option there to reset, but I download many different HD Audio manager still can't get that option back.

Next, I think that must be controlled in Windows 10 registry and just need to find out what is it in the Windows registry.

Does anyone the key/value in the registry, so I can make the popup comes up again when plugin the headphone and pick the right selection.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you look in Control Panel, Auto Play. Device options and what to do are in there.

Comment: Hi, I checked, there is nothing to do for that one, in the old version of HD Audio manager, there is folder icon, which when you click it, it can change it but not in the latest HD Audio manager. Thanks!

Comment: Uninstall any / all Audio Managers, restart and install only the best one.

Comment: Listen to @John . I aggressively disable startup items and unneeded services and I ended up with the same situation.  Uninstall and re-install of the audio device fixed it for me.

Comment: So I will post an answer and hopefully you will find it helpful

Answer (score 1):

> Did you look in Control Panel, Auto Play. Device options and what to
>   do are in there  ....   Hi, I checked, there is nothing to do for that
>   one, in the old version of HD Audio manager, there is folder icon,
>   which when you click it, it can change it but not in the latest HD
>   Audio manager. Thanks!

Uninstall any / all Audio Managers, restart and install only the best one. You may need to use Device Manager to get everything uninstalled

Comment: I uninstall the HD Audio Manager and try downloaded many different versions of the HD Audio Manager and re-install it, unfortunately, the option still not in any of the versions I downloaded. Will try uninstall the audio device/driver instead from the device manager.